# how to close this pop up window?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

how could i close this pop up window?
in this code i open a popup window that shows some code in another page. i need a BUTTON to close this pop up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlhttp;
    function showpopup(id) {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'more-messages.php?id=' + id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

    <a href='#' onclick=\"showpopup($id)\">link to ID</a>
    <div id='popup' style='background-color: #888888; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0.4; display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%'>
    </div>
    <div id='response' style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 40%; margin-top: 14.5%; margin-left: 30%; border: 1px solid balck; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 25px;'>
    </div>
```

Comment: **There is no popup window.** You just made a `<div>` visible. Just hide it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 'popup' is just a `div` element with style attribute `display: none;`, you can make it invisible again like so:

Add this into your JavaScript:

```
function closepopup() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';

    // and maybe this:
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = "";
}
```

and this into your HTML to make a clickable link to close the 'popup'

```
<a href="#" onclick="closepopup()">Close the popup</a>
```

This is effectively just undoing what your showpopup function does.

Answer (score 0):

OR if you have open custom div with some css properties could just hide it like

```
document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
```

in child page you can write function like

```
    <html>
<head>

    <script language="Javascript">

        function redirectToFB(){
            window.opener.location.href="http://wwww.yourdomain.com";
            self.close();
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    Allow the user to view FB
    <br/>Are you sure?
    <input type="button" value="Ok" OnClick="redirectToFB()" />

</body>
```

let me know if i can help you more